# Where does the select/merge between view (linked server) and target table execute?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have a VIEW that selects data from linked server (SvrB) with a WHERE clause.

On the SvrA:

1. When I run a SELECT query on this view, is there a guarantee that the WHERE clause will execute on the SvrB and filtered data will be brought into SvrA?
2. When I run a MERGE using the above view (as source), is there a guarantee that the view will be filtered on SvrB and that then the MERGE will get executed on the SvrA? Or can it happen that all the data (without applying the where clause) is brought from SvrB, then filtered by where clause in SvrA. Then Merge performed.

Any links on this topic?

Comment: Yes I have updated that now to make clear thanks

Comment: Seems essentially a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183737/where-do-linked-server-queries-get-executed i.e. "where does the query get executed?"

Comment: View the actual execution plan to show where the filtering currently occurs. It is not a guarantee of how the query will be executed in the future. The plan is optimized based on row count estimates, indexes, and statistics so the optimizer will choose whether to filter locally or remotely.

Comment: To guarantee the execution of where filter on the SvrB I see that there is something called OPENQUERY. Any idea on the possible issues of using this OPENQUERY approach please?

Comment: There is also a setting called Collation Compatible that ensures that all filters get executed on the linked server. However I cannot find any documentation for guaranteed behaviour. Any help?